# Did Swami Vivekananda meet Sri Bamakhepa?

Tags: vivekananda, bamakhepa

According to a biography of Sri Sri Bamakhepa written by Bipul Kumar Gangopadhyay (Mahapith Tarapith, Vol 2), Swami Vivekananda met Sri Sri Bamakhepa at Tarapith.

Can anybody provide any such evidence from Swamiji's authentic biographies?

Comment: I saw their meeting in a serial dedicated to Bamakhepa.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury these are soap opera. i need authentic source:)